# Smarty: cannot use the same template twice

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, smarty

I'm having the following Smary template (it's a file-tree, files are populated separately and then `list_html` is assigned to geberated file tree hrml)

```
<script>
    $("#directory-list-root").on("click", "div.content", function() {
        $("div.selected", "#directory-list-root").removeClass("selected");
        $(this).addClass("selected");

        // Check if directory is expanded
        var node = $(this).parent("li.directory");
        if (node.hasClass("expanded")) {
            node.removeClass("expanded");
            $(this).siblings("ul.container").hide();
        } else {
            node.addClass("expanded");
            $(this).siblings("ul.container").show();
        }
    } );
</script>

<div id="directory-list-root">
    <ul class="container" style="padding:5px" id="tree">
{$list_html}
    </ul>
</div>
```

In the code it's used twice (in jquery-ui dialogs that are shown one after another). And the problem is that for the first time handling function is OK, but for the second click-handler is not working. If I remove tree from the first dialog then handlers in the second are assigned.

Do you know how that can be fixed?

Thank you in advance!

**PS.** I'm running Smarty `3.1.13` if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the template is used twice there will be two elements with the id `directory-list-root` in the document, which is illegal. The result is that things won't work.

Instead of using a fixed id, use a dynamic one by incrementing an internal counter variable each time, e.g. by using [`{counter}`](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.custom.functions.tpl#language.function.counter):

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        {counter name=tree assign=uniqueId}
        var $root = $("#directory-list-root-{$uniqueId}");

        $root.on("click", /* etc */);
    });
</script>

<div id="directory-list-root-{$uniqueId}">
    <ul class="container" style="padding:5px" id="tree">
{$list_html}
    </ul>
</div>
```